# Concat incremental INT at end of duplicate usernames

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bunch of duplicate usernames for example 2 users are named "goku" and 3 users are name "sliceoflife", etc.

I know this is fairly simple to do in php but is there a way to concat an incremental integer directly in MySQL.

Result should give me for example again

goku
goku1
sliceoflife
sliceoflife1
sliceoflife2
and so on ...

Would be even better if I based the incrementation on the `Date` column `DateLastActive`.

Comment: Please share the create table statement with some example data

Comment: If `username` is used for logging in it should probably have a `UNIQUE` index anyway.

Comment: @CD001 this is migrated data that I'm trying to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to run it like this (where `id` represents your autonumber)

```
UPDATE table SET
username = CONCAT(username, id)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer although this is not the result I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

**Create table/insert data.**

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES('goku');
INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES('goku');

INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES('sliceoflife');
INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES('sliceoflife');
INSERT INTO USER (NAME) VALUES('sliceoflife');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM USER
```

**Result**

```
name         
-------------
goku         
goku         
sliceoflife  
sliceoflife  
sliceoflife
```

This is possible with user variables.

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
   *
   , (
      CASE
        WHEN
          @user = User.name
        THEN
          @rank := @rank + 1

        WHEN
          @user != User.name
        THEN
          @rank := ''

        END
      )
       AS 
        rank
   , @user := User.name
  FROM 
    USER
  CROSS JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
       @user := ''
     , @rank := ''
   ) 
    AS 
     init_user_vars 
  ORDER BY
    User.name ASC
```

**Result**

```
name         @user := ''  @rank := ''  rank    @user := User.name  
-----------  -----------  -----------  ------  --------------------
goku                                           goku                
goku                                   1       goku                
sliceoflife                                    sliceoflife         
sliceoflife                            1       sliceoflife         
sliceoflife                            2       sliceoflife
```

Now it easy to CONCAT name and rank.
You need to use the above query as delivered table.

```
SELECT
  (
    CASE 
     WHEN rank IS NOT NULL 
     THEN CONCAT(NAME, rank)

     WHEN rank IS NULL
     THEN CONCAT(NAME)
    END
   )
    AS
     NAME
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   *
   , (
      CASE
        WHEN
          @user = User.name
        THEN
          @rank := @rank + 1

        WHEN
          @user != User.name
        THEN
          @rank := ''

        END
      )
       AS 
        rank
   , @user := User.name
  FROM 
    USER
  CROSS JOIN ( 
    SELECT 
       @user := ''
     , @rank := ''
   ) 
    AS 
     init_user_vars 
   ORDER BY
    User.name  
)
  AS
    user_ranked
```

**Result**

```
name          
--------------
goku          
goku1         
sliceoflife   
sliceoflife1  
sliceoflife2
```